# A Google web service that returns multiple postal codes

Tags: google-maps

I have a requirement whereby the webservice request could contain a "fuzzy" address and the webservice response returns all postal codes. For example, I enter Lewisville, KY and get all zip codes used within the Louisville,KY area.

Comment: Great for you! Let us know how it goes.

Comment: You go! Don't let anyone stop you!

Comment: On a serious point, you need to publish whatever solution you've tried so far, and identify the *specific* issues you're having

Comment: Wow. Tough crowd. Google does a good job handling fuzzy addresses. I'm just asking if one of the web services does in fact return multiple zip codes. I see nothing in the documentation. If that doesn't exist, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't have any endpoint that can return all postal codes related to the locality.

As a workaround you can try to retrieve this information in two steps:

1. Execute geocoding request for the locality which will return bounds of this feature.
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lewisville%2C%20KY&key=YOUR_API_KEY
2. Now, having bounds organize a loop from min lat to max lat and from min lng to max lng and execute reverse geocoding of form 
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.2526647%2C%20-85.7584557&result_type=postal_code&key=YOUR_API_KEY. So, you can figure out how many different postal codes exist within the bounds.